# Beego raw sql - Type conversion issue

Tags: sqlite, go, beego

Here is the code used inside the Beego MVC architecture.

```
var maps []orm.Params
//Pallets Completed already.
o.Raw("Select SUM(Things) as AllTheThings FROM SomeTable").Values(&maps)

numThings := strconv.Atoi(maps[0]["AllTheThings"].(string))

c.Data["Stuff"] = maps[0]["AllTheThings"]
```

Error:
multiple-value strconv.Atoi() in single-value context

Trying to figure out how I can get data out with our ORM and type cast it so arithmetic can be done on it.

Any more details please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strconv.Atoi](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) has a signature of:

```
func Atoi(s string) (int, error)
```

you should check the error before using the result, like so:

```
var maps []orm.Params
//Pallets Completed already.
o.Raw("Select SUM(Things) as AllTheThings FROM SomeTable").Values(&maps)

numThings, err := strconv.Atoi(maps[0]["AllTheThings"].(string))
if err != nil {
    // couldn't convert
}

c.Data["Stuff"] = maps[0]["AllTheThings"]
```

Comment: Ahhh. silly rookie mistake, the issue seemed to be not dealing with error.

Thanks.